Speed gauge needle malfunction
i'm trying to create a speed gauge with a custom needle,  and when i try to run the code weird things happen to my needle. It has it's own qml file the code is down below and i called it as a omponent in my speed.qml .
this is how my needle is behaving :
(https://i.sstatic.net/rh0cVYkZ.png) (https://i.sstatic.net/TpuNlgJj.png)
it just keeps going back and forth between those two positions.
this is the speedNeedle.qml code:
import QtQuick 6.2

Item {
    id: speedNeedle
    property int value: 0
    property int startAngle: 0
    property real angleLength: 1.0

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Rectangle {
        id: needle
        width: speedNeedle.width * 0.02
        height: speedNeedle.height * 0.45
        color: "red"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        antialiasing: true
        y: id_root.height * 0.05

        transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: needle.width / 2
            origin.y: needle.height
            angle: speedNeedle.startAngle + speedNeedle.value * speedNeedle.angleLength
        }
    }
}

and this is the speed.qml code:
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Controls 6.2

Item {
    id: id_root
    property int value: 0

    Rectangle {
        id: id_speed

        property int numberIndexs: 11
        property int startAngle: 234
        property int angleLength: 23
        property int maxSpeed: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: Math.min(id_root.width, id_root.height)
        width: height
        radius: width / 2
        color: "black"
        border.color: "light green"
        border.width: id_speed.height * 0.02

        Repeater {
            model: id_speed.numberIndexs

            Item {
                height: id_speed.height / 2
                transform: [
                    Rotation {
                        origin.x: 0
                        origin.y: id_speed.height / 2
                        angle: index * id_speed.angleLength + id_speed.startAngle
                    }
                ]
                x: id_speed.width / 2

                Rectangle {
                    height: id_speed.height * 0.05
                    width: height / 2
                    color: "light green"
                    antialiasing: true
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: id_speed.height * 0.03
                }

                Text {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    x: 0
                    y: id_speed.height * 0.09
                    color: "light green"
                    rotation: 360 - (index * id_speed.angleLength + id_speed.startAngle)
                    text: index * (id_speed.maxSpeed / (id_speed.numberIndexs - 1))
                    font.pixelSize: id_speed.height * 0.05
                    font.family: "Comic Sans MS"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: id_center

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: id_speed.height * 0.1
        width: height
        radius: width / 2
        color: "red"
    }

    Text {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: id_speed.verticalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: id_speed.height * 0.1
        text: "Speed\n km/h"
        color: "light green"
        font.pixelSize: id_speed.height * 0.1
        font.family: "Comic Sans MS"
    }

    SpeedNeedle {
        id: id_speedNeedle
        anchors {
            top: id_speed.top
            bottom: id_speed.bottom
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
        value: id_root.value
        startAngle: id_speed.startAngle
        angleLength: id_speed.angleLength / (id_speed.maxSpeed / (id_speed.numberIndexs - 1))
    }
}

any ideas how to fix it also if you have any suggestion on how to improve my code you are welcome to tell me and thank you!
i tried using other code alternatives given by chatgpt but it still the same problem.i'm expecting when i run the application my needle stays in one position which is the first value(in this case is 0).

The rotation is pretty simple:
Item {
    x: xCenter
    y: yCenter
    rotation: // play with this value
    Rectangle {
        id: needle
        // define the thing you want to rotate
    }
}

To mock up your requirements, the background of your speed gauge can be burnt into a PNG and then the only animating bit is the red needle.
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "SpeedGuage.png"
    }
    
    Item {
        id: needle
        x: img.width / 2 - 2
        y: img.height / 2
        property real startAngle: -125
        property real endAngle: 104
        property real speed: speedSlider.value
        rotation: (speed / 200.0) * (endAngle - startAngle) + startAngle
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            x: -5
            y: -150
            width: 10
            height: 150
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: speedSlider
        y: 400
        from: 0
        to: 200.0
    }

You can Try it Online!

when you say play with this value what do you mean, like what are the parameters for the "rotation:"

That rotation is mere a number. Through trial and error I determined the start and end angles and deduced the gauge range.
